# What version of PowerShell is required for SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

Today I tried to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on my computer but I the installation failed, it said that PowerShell must be installed on it.

My question is then, what version of PowerShell should I install? where do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell 1.0 is required according to the [Hardware and Software Requirements for SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx). If you're running this on an old version of Windows, you'll probably need quite a few other updates.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell 2.0 is the current release and will provide expanded functionality for SQL Server.  You can download it from this page: [PS2 Download](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx)